# asp.net load file class library

Tags: asp.net, class-library

I'm working on asp.net (vb, maybe that can change something)

I have a project using as class library.
I want it to load a text file.
the file is on a folder on this project

usely I use "File.Exists" and "Server.MapPath("~")".
but I do not have Server lib.

I look a way to use the file as content or resource. but I didnt succed for the moment(probably my fault)

So if you know a way to do what I want?
Or how to use the file as a resource like by stream or something else?

I looked at this but my first try not working (http://keithelder.net/2007/12/14/How-To-Load-an-Embedded-Resource-From-A-DLL/)

Comment: I will have little problem, because my framework didn't copy my text file to iis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `System.Web` as a project reference to your class library, and use `HttpContext`:

```
using System.Web;

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/somefolder/somefile.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: I try, httpcontext can be use. but with ... I get an high level exception : System.Web.HttpException failed to get...

Comment: It can or it can't be used? Assuming you meant that it can't be used, why?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") is the of root my site, but MapPath("..."); 
 cause an error

Comment: The ellipses ("...") was intended to be a placeholder for the path to the file. I updated my answer so it's a little more clear.

Comment: tanks, its working. (just need to found the way that my VS copy my file into IIS.)

Comment: found it, just need a xcopy on after gen